# Agda: proving that, when values are equal, their constructor arguments are equal

Tags: types, logic, agda, dependent-type, formal-verification

I'm trying to write the following function:

```
justEq : ∀ {A} -> (x y : A) -> (just x ≡ just y) -> (x ≡ y)
justEq x y pf = {!!}
```

I don't know how to write this. To me, it is intuitive to the point of being axiomatic, but the compiler doesn't accept refl as a proof of it.

I'm routinely having to prove these sorts of things, for example, showing that if two non-empty lists are equal, then their heads are equal.

What is the general approach to this? Is this related to Conor McBride's "green-goo" of having functions in the return of Constructors?

Comment: Have you tried pattern matching on `pf`?

Comment: emacs just expands it to `refl`... I'm probably missing the obvious, but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: I feel like `cong` would be useful here, but I don't know how to write a function that takes `just x` to `x`, since it would inherently be partial.

Comment: Once you pattern match on `eq`, Agda has the additional information that `x = y` - this means that `refl` is now accepted as a correct right hand side. As for `cong`... yes, you can do that, but I can't think of any way that doesn't involve very ugly helper functions.

Comment: [Here](http://lpaste.net/134633) is how `justEq` can be defined via `cong`.

Comment: @Vitus: I tried the following: `justEq : {A : Set} -> (x : A) -> (y : A) -> (just x ≡ just y) -> (x ≡ y)
justEq x y refl = refl
` and I get the error `x != y of type .A
when checking that the expression refl has type x ≡ y`

Comment: @user3237465 I'll try that... could you explain it a bit? I'm not terribly familiar with the standard library. What is the `α` doing?

Comment: @jmite, you shouldn't use my version. Use `justEq x .x refl = refl`. Or make `x` and `y` implicit and define `justEq` as `justEq refl = refl`. `α` is a [level](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.UniversePolymorphism).

Comment: @user3237465 Thanks! It works when I use your type signatures with the levels.

Comment: @user3237465: I suspected there would be a nice solution with heterogeneous equality. Nice one!

Answer (score 3):

The basis of the solution is to pattern match on `pf` being `refl` **together** with using a dotted pattern for `y` being equal to `x` (because of the type of `refl`!).

```
justEq : ∀ {A} -> (x y : A) -> (just x ≡ just y) -> (x ≡ y)
justEq x .x refl = {!!}
```

At this point, the type of the hole on the right-hand side has been unified to `(x ≡ x)` because of the `y = .x` equality from the pattern match, meaning you can use `refl` as a well-typed value, giving

```
justEq x .x refl = refl
```